# How to do "with not pytest.raises"?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I want to cancel dialog and check that javascript alert is not displayed. How can I do it? "with not pytest.raises" doesn't work. Thanks

```
# try to cancel the dialog and check that JavaScript alert is displayed
with pytest.raises(UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
    page.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnexpectedAlertPresentException` raised in case *you don't expect alert, but alert is actually present* while you need `NoAlertPresentException` which raised in case *you want to handle alert, but there are no alerts*:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

with pytest.raises(NoAlertPresentException):
    driver.switch_to.alert()
```

This test should passed as we're trying to switch to alert which is not there and `NoAlertPresentException` raised as we expect

Comment: Great answer, just maybe add the `page.cancel()` before the `switch_to.alert()`.

Comment: @MosheSlavin , I'm just not sure what `page.cancel()` might mean, so I decided not to include that line.

Comment: That's a good way for the answer to be reusable! didn't think of that...!